# Generate all possible unique samples with n-elements from

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

Is there any simple way to generate all possible unique samples from any given sample frame eg. I have a list with 5 elements members = ['P', 'V', 'S', 'T', 'A'], and would like to draw all possible 2 element combinations, disregarding an order i.e 'PV' is equivalent to 'VP'. So from list ['P', 'V', 'S', 'T', 'A'], I should get 10, 2 element samples.

I created something that does the trick, but I wonder if there is some method or function available already that does it and would allow to simply provide sample frame, size of the sample and created all possible combinations.

```
members = list('PVSTA')
ms = []

   for i in members:
       for j in members:
           if i != j and i+j not in ms and j+i not in ms:
               ms.append(i+j)
           else:
               continue
print(ms)
['PV', 'PS', 'PT', 'PA', 'VS', 'VT', 'VA', 'ST', 'SA', 'TA']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) which return `r` length subsequences of elements from the input iterable. So in your case when the iterable is `['P', 'V', 'S', 'T', 'A']` and `r=2` it will return **<sup>5</sup>C<sub>2</sub> = 10** combinations.

Use:

```
from itertools import combinations

ms = ["".join(c) for c in combinations(list("PVSTA"), r=2)]
print(ms)
```

Output:

```
['PV', 'PS', 'PT', 'PA', 'VS', 'VT', 'VA', 'ST', 'SA', 'TA']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called the combinations, you can do this by using the `itertools` library in python.

```
from itertools import combinations

members = list('PVSTA') 
comb_2 = combinations(members, 2) 
result = ["".join(c) for c in comb_2] 
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already posted the itertools.combinations route (the best approach), but here is the manual way to do it for anyone interested:

```py
members = list('PVSTA')
ms = []
for i in range(len(members)-1):
  for j in range(i+1, len(members)):
    ms.append(members[i] + members[j]
print(ms) # ['PV', 'PS', 'PT', 'PA', 'VS', 'VT', 'VA', 'ST', 'SA', 'TA']
```